# counter not incrementing due to sscanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I have a function that reads and parses a file, but the valid_lines counter does not increment despite the printf right under it is working as expected. I have tried commenting out different parts of the function and it seems that the `if (sscanf...` block might be causing this issue.

```c
void read_file(char *filename, int *city_num_lines, double *city_min, double *city_max, double *city_avg) {
    // files are in data_files/ directory
    char path[LINE_MAX_LENGTH] = "data_files/";
    strcat(path, filename);

    FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");

    // check if file exists
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Could not open file %s\n", filename);
        return;
    }

    char buffer[LINE_MAX_LENGTH];
    int valid_lines = 0;
    double min = BIG_NUM;
    double max = -BIG_NUM;
    double sum = 0;
    double avg = 0;

    // read line by line
    while (fgets(buffer, LINE_MAX_LENGTH, file) != NULL) {
        // skip first line
        if (buffer[0] == 'm') {
            continue;
        }

        // separate by tab (\t)
        double cur_max, cur_min;
        char delim;
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%lf%[\t]%lf", &cur_max, &delim, &cur_min) != 3) {
            // printf("skipped line %s", buffer);
            continue;
        }

        // increment line count
        valid_lines++;
        printf("num_lines incremented\n");

        // update min and max
        if (cur_max > max) {
            max = cur_max;
            printf("max: %lf\n", max);
        }
        if (cur_min < min) {
            min = cur_min;
            printf("min: %lf\n", min);
        }
        sum += (cur_max + cur_min) / 2;
        // printf("%lf - %lf\n", min, max);

    }

    printf("num_lines: %d\n", valid_lines);

    // calculate average
    avg = sum / valid_lines;

    // update city values
    *city_num_lines = valid_lines;
    *city_min = min;
    *city_max = max;
    *city_avg = avg;

    fclose(file); // close file
}
```

here is the console output (last few lines as it goes on forever)

```
...
num_lines incremented
num_lines incremented
num_lines incremented
num_lines incremented
num_lines incremented
num_lines incremented
num_lines incremented
num_lines incremented
num_lines incremented
num_lines incremented
num_lines incremented
num_lines incremented
num_lines incremented
num_lines incremented
num_lines: 1
```

Does anyone have any idea at all why this is happening?

UPDATE:
The root cause of the problem had been the `"%lf%[\t]%lf"` within sscanf, as I had only given it 1 space for the character however it ends with a NUL character, causing it to affect another part of memory, which in this case was the `valid_lines` variable.

Comment: I cannot spot anything wrong with the posted code. Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: The code is fairly clean and well written. The issue looks to be `sscanf()` doing its job and the `!= 3` likely calling `continue` and skipping the remainder of the loop. That can only be determined by your input file (post 10 or so lines)

Comment: Either `buffer[0] == 'm' `or you don't have 3 fields.   I suggest you rework the interface to pass in a `FILE *` and let caller open the file.  Then you can hard-code your data into main and use `fmemopen()` to obtain a file handle.  Alternatively, shows us a main and content of file you are a parsing.  Without proper error handling you are wasting time.

Comment: `if (sscanf(buffer, "%lf%[\t]%lf", &cur_max, &delim, &cur_min) != 3)` The correct way to discard a character is to use `%*[\t]` Without seeing the source data, it's possible the load is writing multiple characters into a single char `delim`...

Comment: Ditch the `delim` reading, you don't need it and you are doing it wrong. `scanf`  family functions skip the whitespace just fine. Just do `sscanf("%lf%lf", ...)`.

Comment: It's odd you use LINE_MAX_LENGTH for max path, btw.

Comment: I swear, this is the first time I've seen a `*scanf()` related question where the example *actually checks the return value*... +1 for that alone. Youu restored my faith in humanity. :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%[\t]` conversion will write the TAB character, plus a terminating NUL character, but you have only given it space for one character.

Comment: If that is the cause, then the likely solution is `"%lf %lf"` and a change to `!= 2`

Comment: ... or use a * to ignore the field.

Comment: But if it is whitespace, `%lf` will discard it anyway, so conceivably `%lf%lf` would be fine, just less readable.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Unless that it matter for OP whether the file has a space or a tab

Comment: This is a nice catch. The answer could be improved by mentioning `char delim` and further by mentioning that `%[\t]` should never be used without a maximum field width.

Comment: This was the issue! I tried what @DavidC.Rankin suggested and it seemed to fix the issue. However, now it accepts \t and regular whitespace characters, when I only want it to accept \t characters. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `sscanf(buffer, "%lf%*[\t]%lf", &cur_max, &cur_min) != 2`

Comment: @AllanWind That will only require a tab after the first double and then allow spaces

Comment: @SupportUkraine If op wants to disallow spaces I don't they `sscanf()` will be up to the task.

Comment: @h4ppyturt1e How strict do you want the parsing? Only `\t` between doubles? Are multiple `\t` allowed?

Comment: I need it to strictly accept only a single \t. @AllanWind Thanks for the suggestion but Ukraine is right

Comment: @h4ppyturt1e And how about spaces or tabs **before** the first double? Is that allowed?

Comment: @SupportUkraine the input file has a specification against that so there is no need :D

Comment: @h4ppyturt1e -- is there some reason you only want to accept a single `'\t'` char? If that is the case, then is seems like you need to rethink the read a bit. Normally, you want to let `sscanf()` do its job and ignore any amount of whitespace -- which provides flexibility if your data file contains an extra space around the tab on some lines, etc... You may have a valid reason for only wanting 1-tab, but make sure you are not making things harder on yourself than they need to be. `strtod()` is another option.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think I will go for this instead, thanks!

Comment: @h4ppyturt1e I agree with D.C.Rankin. If you want a strict parsing then `sscanf` is probably not the tool to use. When using `sscanf` it's best to follow the "parsing rules" designed into it

Comment: strtod() also ignores leading whitespace.

Comment: @AllanWind - yep, but using the `endptr` parameter, you have a pointer to the next character after the last conversion -- so you can check the next character manually `:)`

Answer (score 1):

1. Check size of filename otherwise `strcat()` may cause a buffer overflow.  It might be easier to use use `snprintf()` then check if the `path` generated is too long (defined as LINE_MAX_LENGTH -1 or longer).
2. `fgets()` will return multiple partial read for long lines.  The strict parser will catch this.
3. `delim` is 1 byte but you require at least 2.  Also, when reading strings always use maximum field width.  I suggest you ignore the delimiter with the '*' like this:

```
sscanf(buffer, "%lf%*[\t]%lf", &cur_max, &cur_min) != 2
```

4. `scanf()` will ignore leading whitespace so you will never be able get it to parse your input strictly as you said was required.
5. You might want to guard against valid_line == 0 before doing
   `avg = sum / valid_lines`.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BIG_NUM 42
#define LINE_MAX_LENGTH 100

void read_file(char *filename, int *city_num_lines, double *city_min, double *city_max, double *city_avg) {
    char path[LINE_MAX_LENGTH];
    snprintf(path, LINE_MAX_LENGTH, "data_files/%s", filename);
    if(strlen(path) + 1 == LINE_MAX_LENGTH) {
        printf("path name too long\n");
        return;
    }
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");
    if (!file) {
        printf("Error: Could not open file %s\n", filename);
        return;
    }

    char buffer[LINE_MAX_LENGTH];
    *city_num_lines = 0;
    *city_min = BIG_NUM;
    *city_max = -BIG_NUM;
    *city_avg = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer, LINE_MAX_LENGTH, file) != NULL) {
        if (buffer[0] == 'm') {
            continue;
        }
        char *p = buffer;
        char *p2;
        // space prefix
        if(isspace(*p)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "skipped line %s", buffer);
            continue;
        }
        double max = strtod(p, &p2);
        // could not parse double, or field is not tab separated
        if(!p2 || (*p2 != '\t' && isspace(*p2))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "skipped line %s", buffer);
            continue;
        }
        p = p2 + 1;
        // 2nd field is space prefixed
        if(isspace(*p)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "skipped line %s", buffer);
            continue;
        }
        double min = strtod(p, &p2); 
        // could not parse double, or we are missing a trailing newline
        if(!p2 || *p2 != '\n') {
            fprintf(stderr, "skipped line %s", buffer);
            continue;
        }
        (*city_num_lines)++;
        if(max > *city_max) *city_max = max;
        if(min < *city_min) *city_min = min;
        *city_avg += (max + min) / 2;
    }
    *city_avg = *city_num_lines ? *city_avg / *city_num_lines : 0;
    fclose(file);
}

int main() {
    int city_num_lines;
    double city_min;
    double city_max;
    double city_avg;
    read_file("1.txt", &city_num_lines, &city_min, &city_max, &city_avg);
    printf("city_num_lines: %d, city_min: %f, city_max: %f, city_avg: %f\n", city_num_lines, city_min, city_max, city_avg);
}
```

With a sample  input file of 1.txt with only the last line being valid:

```
m
x
 1  1
2 2
3   3 
4               4
5       5
```

example session returns:

```
skipped line x
skipped line  1 1
skipped line 2 2
skipped line 3  3 
skipped line 4          4
city_num_lines: 1, city_min: 5.000000, city_max: 5.000000, city_avg: 5.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

OP's code incurs buffer overflow as `char delim` is too small for even a *string* of `"\t"`.

Do not use `"%[...]"` or `"%s"` without a *width*.

```
    // separate by tab (\t)
    double cur_max, cur_min;
    // char delim;
    char delim[2];
    //if (sscanf(buffer, "%lf%[\t]%lf", &cur_max, &delim, &cur_min) != 3) {
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%lf%1[\t]%lf", &cur_max, delim, &cur_min) != 3) {
        // printf("skipped line %s", buffer);
        continue;
    }
```

Above will accept 1 or more `"\t"` between the numeric text as `"%1[\t]"` needs 1 and only 1 `'\t'` and the following `"%lf"` will consume 0 or more leading white-spaces, including tabs - and then the number.

---

If code needs to use `scanf()` and read 1 and only 1 tab between numbers, consider using `"%n"` to record the offset of the scan.  With `"%n%*1[\t] %n"`, anything other than 1 tab will fail `n1 + 1 != n2`.

```
 int n1, n2;
 if (sscanf(buffer, "%lf%n%*1[\t] %n%lf", &cur_max, &n1, &n2, &cur_min) != 2 || 
     n1 + 1 != n2) {
   printf("skipped line <%s>\n", buffer);
 }
```

Alternatively, look to parsing with `strtod()`, `strchr()`, `strtok()`, `strcspn()`, etc.